# Why does Laravel storage uploads files to the storage directory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

Is there any special reason why Laravel storage uploads files to a directory in the storage folder and then require creating a Symbolic link to make those files accessible publicly?, why not just upload those files into a directory in the public folder instead?.
Thanks.

Comment: its so that you can set read-only properties on the public folders and have read/write on the folders outside of public.  But you are able to change the storage config to save direct into public folder if you care.

Comment: It is also very useful when you have redundancy and both instances point to the same file directory.  It may be in another location inside the server. for example /usr/files in your linux server

Comment: @Snapey Thanks for your comment, i do understand the part where the storage directory can be changed so that files are uploaded to a folder in the public directory.
But i am a bit confused about the directory permissions, if Laravel is able to write files to this folder, doesn't that mean the folder has write access?, and makes no different from the outside folders?

Comment: @JoeGalind Cool, so you have like two instances of the same laravel application and then you configure your laravel storage driver to write to say, /usr/files, then you create a symbolic link in both instances pointing to this central directory?

Comment: exactly! and they share that storage between them